# VK API | Лимит символом для отправки

Tags: c#, вконтакте, api

```
case "!инфа":
                            sendMessages(idChat.ToString(), "Командный центр" + n +
                                "!погода [город] - выводит расширенную информацию о погоде в выбранном городе." + n +
                                "!укоротить [домен/сайт/ссылка] - в ответ получите сокращенную ссылку типа vk.cc" + n +
                                "!курс - выводит курс валют в рублях, с последней датой обновления." + n +
                                "!дата - расширенная информация, такая как полная дата, день недели, время по МСК, сколько осталось до лета." + n +
                                "!шанс - выводит шанс в процентах." + n +
                                "!вики [слово] - выводит краткое содержание из статьи Wikipedia, прикрепляя ссылку на статью. (если указываете несколько слов, то указывайте вот так, Пример: Владимир_Владимирович_Путин)" + n +
                                "Игровые команды" + n +
                                "!зарегистрировать - регистрирует аккаунт в нашем боте." + n +
                                "!профиль - выводит Ваш профиль, с подробной информацией." + n +
                                "!ставка [сумма ставки] - настоящие кaзинo в виртуальном мире, шанс на победу и проигрыш 50%." + n +
                                "!топ - выводит ТОП10 игроков." + n +
                                "!магазин - выводит категории товаров.", idMessages);
                            break;
```

Данный текст не отправляется, но если отправлять в ручную, то отправка идет успешно.

Метод отправки сообщения:

```
var send = WebClient.DownloadString("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?peer_id=" + chat_id + "&forward_messages=" + idmess + "&random_id=" + idmess + "&message=" + messages + "&access_token=" + token + "&v=5.74");
```

Comment: При отправке сообщения посмотрите что вообще вы отправляете, посмотрите длину и сравните... И как вообще понять `Не отправляется` Ошибка, или что? Если да, то какая?

Comment: Ошибки нет, судя по всему, просто пустой ответ. Вообще пустой.

Comment: Отправляю этот текст:
https://pastebin.com/44SpbTbp
Сюда не поместился

Всего символов: 857
Всего символов без пробелов: 748
Количество слов: 110

Comment: Ну если пустой ответ и без ошибок, то значит отправляете не так. Ну а вообще, сервер [отдает](https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send) всегда какую либо информацию, пустой она не может быть!  Кстати, для указания параметров в WebClient есть специальные методы (`webClient.QueryString.Add("param1", "value1");` к примеру, это уберет все, что после знака `?` в вашем запросе.

Comment: Убираю две строки, сообщение отправляется.
Может я превысил какой-то лимит на символы ? про который как раз нигде не указано

Comment: Лимит сообщения раньше был в районе 4к символов, а сами Get запросы у большинства серверов ограничены приемом запроса в размере вроде как не выше 8кб, так что до ограничений вам вроде далеко. Ну а вообще, у VK api есть специальная ошибка, которая отправляется сервером при достижение порога длины - это номер `914 - Сообщение слишком длинное`.